# How to assign a sequence of integers from a given row in R?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have the following data, with binary variable `x`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
                 year = c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004"),
                 x = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0))

 id year x
  a 2001 0
  a 2002 0
  a 2003 1
  a 2004 0
  b 2001 0
  b 2002 1
  b 2003 1
  b 2004 0
```

I want to create a variable `y` that assigns a sequence of integers where `y = 0` for the first instance of `x = 1`. The ideal output:

```
 id year x  y
  a 2001 0 -2
  a 2002 0 -1
  a 2003 1  0
  a 2004 0  1
  b 2001 0 -1
  b 2002 1  0
  b 2003 1  1
  b 2004 0  2
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can translate to dplyr `ave(df$x, df$id, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) - which(x == 1)[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 df %>%
    mutate(y = row_number() - which(x==1)[1], .by = id)

  id year x  y
1  a 2001 0 -2
2  a 2002 0 -1
3  a 2003 1  0
4  a 2004 0  1
5  b 2001 0 -1
6  b 2002 1  0
7  b 2003 1  1
8  b 2004 0  2
```